# current electricity and voltaic cell

Tags: electric-current

let us consider that i have a voltaic cell in an open circuit that has copper plate at higher potential w.r.t zinc plate. Now my query is, since the electrolyte separating them is a conducting medium, the positive and negative charges on the electrodes must get neutralised immediately(i think so)...But it doesnt happen as i assume? What actually might be my failure in understanding....i do think m ryte....help!

Comment: when the charge will flow to create balance it will create electricity

Comment: ohh really...??? Wud u kindly elucidate please....

Comment: The neutralisation do not happen immediately as some time is needed for the cleavage of bond from the electrode and electrolyte and  charge to flow from one side to another to neutralise the potential difference

Comment: Please define "electricity." There is current, potential difference, power, and energy. There is no such thing as "electricity" so I'm puzzled by what you mean by "it will create electricity."

Answer (score 1):

The neutralization process *is* the flow of electrons/electricity, and this process does not happen immediately.

[image: The electron flow *is* the elctricity]{1}
[image] {2}

{1}http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/Electricity%20-%20Basic%20Navy%20Training%20Courses/images/Figure%2026.jpg
{2}http://image.wistatutor.com/content/redox-reactions/electrolysis-process.jpeg

"Electricity is the set of physical phenomena associated with the presence and flow of electric charge."-[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity)